# Detect client connect/disconnect hotspot

Tags: android, wifi

I saw someone asked this question but no possible answer. I am building a hotspot app. I want to listen when a client connect or disconnect to the hotspot (like samsung rom does). The only things I can do right now is detecting client connect/disconnect when my hotspot is set password. I logcat process hostapd and find out there are 2 line: "AP-STA-CONNECTED" and "AP-STA-DISCONNECTED". But in Open mode, there isn't.
So, is there anyway else?

P.s: It seems the package "AP-STA-DISCONNECTED" of process hostapd depends on the kernel of a rom, because when I tested on samsung stock roms, it appeared even in Open mode, but when I tested on CM10.1 roms, it didn't. Is it because of hostapd.conf or wpa-supplicant.conf?

Comment: "I saw someone asked this question but no possible answer." duplicate?

Comment: I don't know. It is more than 1 year ago and seems nobody care.

Comment: I was seeking this answer too, do you got answer?

Comment: i was seeking this answer too... please updae if you found solution